# How to seek only video with external audio in mplayer?

Tags: audio, sync, mplayer, video-playback

I have a separate video and audio file. The audio basically would cover only a part of the video. They differ greatly in length with the video being much longer. (My video is several hours long while the audio is 10 minutes.)

Is it possible with mplayer to seek the video to a given second to start, and start the external audio file from the beginning, synced to this point?

Note that I could do video editing but that's not my point, and I don't need a permanent solution.

What I've tried is e.g.  `mplayer -ss 1:30:00 -delay -5400 big_video.mkv -audiofile tiny_audio.flac` but it hang. I've tried it with smaller values and the audio seemed to be seeked too, not just the video.

Comment: If the audio is not synced, why don't you play it separately?

Comment: @yi_H because I don't know how could I sync the video playback with the audio then. Playing separately may introduce a small delay at startup. The user (me:)) may also want to pause the playback, or do a fastforward or backward.